# Mass fix for outdated links to PostgreSQL development docs

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, clean-up

The PostgreSQL team has **moved their development docs** to a new site, as is documented in [this thread on pgsql-www](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-www/2011-12/msg00006.php) and [on the PostgreSQL website](http://www.postgresql.org/developer/testing/). Old links were broken for a couple of days but have (mostly) been fixed by now and get redirected. However, the **PostgreSQL team encourages to update links**, as you can read in the thread above.

[Discussion of officially available PostgreSQL docs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual).

I checked for old links to the PostgreSQL developer docs with a [search on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22*developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs*%22&submit=search):

I also wrote [**a query on data.SE to check posts and comments**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/55449/mass-fix-for-outdated-links-to-postgresql-development-docs). I did not find a way to search for comments in the search interface on SO. The search uses considerable resources, so I picked one example and commented out the rest - including an `UPDATE` statement to fix all occurrences.

Found **83 posts** (currently) and **19 comments** (snapshot on data.SE) for SO.
Found **7 posts** and **1 comment** on serverfault.SE.
<strike>Found **2 posts** on superuser.SE.</strike> Fixed those right away.

#### Questions

- I *could* go and edit all the posts, but I cannot fix comments. Also, this is stupid work that should be taken care of by the SQL commands I prepared, and more reliably, too. Can an admin apply the prepared UPDATE statement - provided we can agree upon its usefulness?
- Should we update links to point to the new location of the development docs or to the the docs for the current release. I propose to fix the links properly as practically all of them should point to /current rather than /devel in the first place.

  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/